# Unfortunately, my app has stopped working

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

Can anyone clarify where my error is? The Android app crashes with the error, "Unfortunately, my app has stopped working". The crash only happens when my `activity_main.xml` contains `android:id="@+id/map"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

My MainActivity.java class is equally simple:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I have added the "google-play" dependencies and I am targeting "Google APIs". Again, the app runs fine when I do not attempt to display the map.

Here are the LogCat Errors:

```
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1069)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
01-11 02:04:24.608: E/AndroidRuntime(14416):    ... 11 more
```

**Updated**
And here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- MAPS -->
    <permission android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!-- Allows the API to access Google web-based services -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true"/>
    <!-- 8/17 oneX=16-->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- REMOVED user-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" / -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UDPATED** New LogCat since changing android:minSdkVersion="12" "Use MapFragment only if you are targeting API 12 and above. Otherwise, use SupportMapFragment."

```
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:358)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    ... 11 more
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:624)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4714)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    ... 21 more
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:606)
01-11 11:26:23.267: E/AndroidRuntime(27646):    ... 24 more
```

Comment: have you add permissions to AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: @Sunny show your manifest file

Comment: Have added `MainActivity` in manifest ?

Comment: Check whether MainActivity is declared in AndroidManifest file?

Comment: Post your manifest file to answer your question

Comment: I have updated the original question with the manifest. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I should note that I am testing on an Android running 4.1.1

Comment: Remove <uses-library> tag its not required in V2 Map

Comment: Removed <uses-library> tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is required to use `SupportMapFragment` if `API version is below 11`

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

- Don't forget to extend your **Activity** with **FragmentActivity**

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

  SupportMapFragment mMap;
  GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         mMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
          .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

          googleMap = mMap.getMap();
   }
  }
  ```

Comment: I updated the manifest and MainActivity.java and it is still crashing.

Comment: Also, I have android:minSdkVersion="11"

Comment: I changed android:minSdkVersion="12" after reading, "Use MapFragment only if you are targeting API 12 and above. Otherwise, use SupportMapFragment."

Comment: Thanks! I think this was the fix!

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity
```

Define your activity in AndroidManifest like this

```
<activity
      android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: I have updated the original question with the manifest and it appears that I do have the advised activity attributes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you have defined the `android:minSdkVersion="11"` and the `MapFragment` is only supported on the api 12 or above.

So you have to use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment` as below:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Don't forget to extend your Activity with `FragmentActivity`.

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

           SupportMapFragment mMap;
           GoogleMap googleMap;

        @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             mMap = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                  .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

               googleMap = mMap.getMap();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I changed android:minSdkVersion="12" after reading, "Use MapFragment only if you are targeting API 12 and above. Otherwise, use SupportMapFragment." ...sadly it is still crashing.

Comment: Can you post your latest logcat. What error you are getting now ?

Comment: Thanks! I just updated the original question with the new LogCats

Comment: It is working now! Once I added the Play library again (removed while debugging). I believe the issue was as you described ...and of course adding the google play services dependencies to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Change AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
      android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

And give the permission for map and Internet.

Comment: Yes, both of these are true.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue during some days, and cloning this repo helped me a lot,

https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-android

Good luck